# How to update variables in subscribe?

Tags: angular, apollo-client

I have a service, in this service I initiate a subscription:

session.service.ts

```js
constructor(
  private apollo: Apollo,
  private notificationService: NotificationService
) {
  this.subscribeToSessions();
}

//

private subscribeToSessions(): void {
  this.apollo.subscribe<UserJoinedSession>({
    query: USER_JOINED_SESSION,
    variables: {
      id: this.sessionSubject.getValue()?.id
    },
  }).subscribe({
    next: ({data}) => {
      console.log(data)
    }
  })
}
```

I call this subscription when a user is connected to a session:

session.resolvers.js

```js
connectUserToSession: async (_, args) => {
  const session = await prisma.session.update({
    where: {
      id: Number(args.sessionId)
    },
    data: {
      players: {
        connect: {
          id: Number(args.userId)
        }
      }
    },
    include: {
      players: true,
      host: true
    }
  })

  pubsub.publish('USER_JOINED_SESSION', { userJoinedSession: session })

  return session
},
// working on this
userJoinedSession: {
  subscribe: withFilter(() => pubsub.asyncIterator('USER_JOINED_SESSION'),
    (payload, variables) => {
      console.log(variables)
      return true
    },
  ),
},
```

My goal is to send notifications only  to users who are also connected to that session. To achieve this I want to to send the session object that a user is connected to from the client to the server and then use that in the `withFilter()`.

The problem I'm encountering is that in the client when the service is initiated it initiates the subscriptions with the value of `this.sessionSubject.getValue()?.id` which is `null` (since a user hasn't joined a session yet).

But this value never gets updated. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was quite easy. I don't need to subscribe to changes in a session when I actually haven't joined a session.

So I moved the `USER_JOINED_SESSION` outside of the `subscribeToSessions` function, and into it's own:

```js
private subscribeToSession(): void {
  this.apollo.subscribe<UserJoinedSession>({
    query: USER_JOINED_SESSION,
    variables: {
      ...this.sessionSubject.getValue()
    },
  }).subscribe({
    next: ({data}) => {
      console.log(data)
    }
  })
}`
```

Which I call when I subscribe to a session.